# Definition of a function in a C program

Tags: c, function

In a C program, where do you define a function? 
Why?

I suppose that the function definition is generally written outside the main function and after the function declaration. It's correct? Why?

Thank you all!

Comment: A function is defined outside of the main function. Generally before the main function unless you  use a function prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a function outside `main()`, because `main()` is a function itself and nested functions are not supported in C.

Declaring a function is in modern C not necessary, because a function definition implies a function declaration. There are still two reasons to do it:

- A function declaration can be exported in a header file and then used by other translation units that import the header file.
- C is usually translated one-pass that means that you cannot use a function before it is declared without warning. If you have a function `a()` calling a function `b()`and vice versa, you cannot define both functions before declaring at least one.

Answer (score 2):

The only real requirement is that a function be *declared* before it is first called in a statement, and that it be *defined* somewhere before everything is linked together (either in another source file that gets translated, or in a previously translated object file or library).

If your program is small and you have everything in a single source file, my recommended practice is to *define* the function before it is used, like so:

```
void foo( void )
{
  // body of foo
}

void bar( void )
{
   ...
   foo();
   ...
}    

int main( void )
{
  ...
  bar();
  ...
}
```

The function *definition* also serves as a *declaration* (specifying the return type as well as the number and types of parameters to the function).  You could put the *definitions* after `main`, but you will still need to *declare* them before they're called:

```
int main( void )
{
  void bar( void );
  ...
  bar();
  ...
}

void bar( void )
{
  void foo( void );
  ...
  foo();
  ...
}

void foo ( void )
{
  // body of foo
}
```

You don't have to declare `foo` within the body of `bar`, or `bar` within the body of `main`; you could declare them both before `main:

```
void foo( void );
void bar( void );

int main( void )
{
  ...
  bar();
  ...
}

void bar( void )
{
   ...
   foo();
   ...
 }
```

The only problem with this style is that if you change the return type of the function or change any of the parameters, you have to chase down any declarations and change them as well.  The first way (defining before use) reads "backwards", but it's less of a maintenance headache.

If your program is divided up among multiple source files, the usual practice is to create a separate *header file* for each source file, and `#include` that header in any other source file that uses those functions, like so:

```
/**
 * foo.h - Header file for function foo
 */
#ifndef FOO_H       // Include guards; prevents the file from being processed
#define FOO_H       // more than once within the same translation unit

void foo( void );   // declaration of foo

#endif

/**
 * foo.c - Source file for function foo
 */
#include "foo.h"
...
void foo( void )    // definition of foo
{
  // body of foo
}

/**
 * bar.h - Header file for bar.h
 */
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

void bar( void );   // declaration of bar

#endif

/**
 * bar.c - Source file for bar.h
 */
#include "foo.h"    // necessary because bar calls foo

void bar( void )
{
   ...
   foo();
}

/**
 * main.c - Source file for main
 */
#include "bar.h"  // necessary because main includes bar

int main( void )
{
  ...
   bar();
}
```

Note that the header files only contain the *declarations* of `foo` and `bar`, not their actual code.  In order for this to work, both `foo.c` and `bar.c` must be compiled along with `main.c`, and the resulting object files must all be linked together.  You could do them all at once, like:

```
gcc -o blah main.c foo.c bar.c
```

Or you could compile each separately and link the object files together:

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -c bar.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o blan main.o foo.o bar.o
```

Or you could build a library out of `foo.c` and `bar.c` and link against that (useful if you want to use `foo` and `bar` in other programs):

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -c bar.c

ar cr libblurga.a foo.o bar.o 

gcc -o blah main.c -lblurga
```

Standard C does not support nested functions (that is, defining a function within the body of another function).  Some implementations such as gcc support nested functions as an *extension*, but it's not the usual practice.

Answer (score 0):

Private declaration goes on top of your .c file:

```
static int your_function();
```

Private declaration can be emitted if it is defined above where you are attempting to call it, although for maintainability it's always better to declare your private interface, just like your public, in one place.

Public declaration in your .h file:

```
extern int your_function();
```

Keyword 'extern' in header files is always implicitly added to your function declaration, although I tend to attach it explicitly for clarity.

Function definition works for both private and public declarations:

```
int your_function() {
    return 5;
}
```

Or for private only:

```
static int your_function() {
    return 5;
}
```

If you mark extern function definition as static, GCC will fail with the following:

```
error: static declaration of ‘your_function’ follows non-static declaration
```

When compiler builds your code, it pretty much replaces all your #include statements with the content of the file you are including and the parsing goes from top to bottom as one large file. Once you understand that, most of these things simply start to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Languages in the Pascal family usually do have the concept of scoped functions, like any other declaration/definition.

I think the answer lies in the origins of C as, heaven forgive me, a better macro assembler of sorts (with a standard library). Functions are mere jump addresses with a little stack magic for parameter and return value handling; function "scope" is just too abstract a concept in that world.

That said, a similar effect can be achieved by grouping "helper functions" together with a globally visible function which needs them in the same file; the helper functions would be declared static and could then only be used in that source file. The net effect is quite similar to scoped functions.